# Prerequisites to continuous geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry

Im learning differential equations on youtube with professor Leonard, and am looking to get into continuous geometry for research into ai, and am looking for a list of steps to take before i can dive into theoretical work

Comment: Hi John, I will suggest that you please elaborate and provide more context to your question as it would allow people on the site to help you better. :) Also please change tags to reference request

Answer (score 0):

You can find the bare minimum of the math (not differential geometry) needed to start reading about artificial intelligence in the first chapters of [Goodfellow et al.](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) Then it really depends on what you want to study!

You can study the classical tools for Shape Analysis and Geometry Processing in *Mathematical Tools for Shape Analysis and Description* ([here](http://saturno.ge.imati.cnr.it/ima/personal/biasotti/SGP13/SGP_partI.pdf) an outline of the book) and in *[Polygon mesh processing](https://www.crcpress.com/Polygon-Mesh-Processing/Botsch-Kobbelt-Pauly-Alliez-Levy/p/book/9781568814261)*. A really nice book is the recent [Geometric and Topological Inference](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01615863v2/document).

My advice is to understand what you want to do, check the tools used in the state of the art and then check some syllabuses of relevant courses. The literature can be quite vast and you can't learn everything: is measure theory important? Are stochastic PDEs important? Are simplicial complexes important?